# How to suppress a "SpriteKit Texture Atlas Generator Warning"?

Tags: objective-c, xcode5, pragma, sprite-kit

Xcode is reporting the following warning: "SpriteKit Texture Atlas Generator Warning Splitting 'images.atlas' into 2 texture atlases due to input texture dimensions."  Although I will modified my images in the future to avoid SpriteKit from generating this warning, I would like to temporarily suppress this warning using some pragma directives.  Does anyone know the warning flag to use to suppress this warning using code like the following?

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
// my code
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Or, can this specific warning be suppressed in the build settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to achieve this with pragmas. The texture atlas tool is a separate build step that doesn't involve the compiler.

You can either make the change to reduce your atlas size right now (good idea if you want to do that anyway, so why wait?) or ignore the warning. After all it's reminding you to do what you still need to do.

Comment: While I agree that textures should be as small as possible, what should one do if the textures (with 2x versions) are large?  We have an animated texture that fills a good bit of the screen.  The 2x versions are 800x800 for each image.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I don't understand why we 'need' to do this. The animations work just fine, despite the warning.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm so sorry, I totally mixed that up with another question. Disregard my comments (deleting them now).
In your case you probably don't want to use a texture atlas for these images, at least it's worth a try. At most you could fit 4 of the images in the atlas, and since you only display one of them at a time, an atlas doesn't really help both in performance or loading time.

Answer (score 1):

Set "Enable Texture Atlas Generation" to Yes.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-texture_atlas/Art/EnableSetting_2x.png
[image]