# Splitting texture atlas into multiple texture atlases warning

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

I keep getting a warning message saying "Splitting 'animation.atlas' into 3 texture atlases due to input texture dimensions." It doesn't seem to have any negative affects, but I'm wondering if I need to fix it, and if I do, how I should go about doing that? I would guess that my textures are too big and that is what is causing the warning.

Answer (score 7):

From my understanding and after consulting with this [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19638837/how-to-suppress-a-spritekit-texture-atlas-generator-warning), **you can ignore** or **fix it under settings**.

I couldn't find the ("Enable Texture Atlas Generation") settings talked about in the thread in xCode 7.3, however after reading [Apple Developer Instructions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-texture_atlas/Recipe.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013290-CH1-SW1) I found something called "SpriteKit Texture Atlas Options". I changed the "Texture Atlas Maximum Size" to 4096x4096. Changing this removed the warning. Hope this helps! (If you're still having the problem)